# Inverse Distance Weighting in R

Tags: r, csv, coordinates, interpolation

Trying to interpolate a set of data using IDW. I am able to bring in the csv and convert it to a spatial points data frame. My column headings are lat and lon instead of x and y.

The coordinates are very minimal in distance due to the csv being representative of a farmers field. As a result the code believes that the minimum and maximum coordinates for x and y are the same because of the `as.numeric` dropping the decimal points and rounding the coordinates. 
That is where the code errors out because when I try to run the `expand.grid` it sees no difference in `x.range[1]` and `x.range[2]`.

Does anyone see something that could be fixed? Is there a way to carry more decimal points in my coordinates to make sure there is the difference between `x.range[1]` and `x.range[2]` and similarly for `y.range`?

```
path<- setwd()

library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
#Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
nuclides <- read.csv("fieldnuclides.csv")

#convert this basic data frame into a spatial points data frame
coordinates(nuclides) = ~ lon + lat

## Create a grid from the values in your points dataframe
## first get the range in data
x.range <- as.numeric(range(nuclides@coords[,1]))
y.range <- as.numeric(range(nuclides@coords[,2]))

nuclides.grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 3.5), y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 3.5))
# 
# ## convert grid to SpatialPixel class
coordinates(nuclides.grd) <- ~ x+y
gridded(nuclides.grd) <- TRUE
#
```

my `x.range` and `y.range` summaries are below

```
summary(x.range)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-80.65  -80.64  -80.64  -80.64  -80.64  -80.63 
summary(y.range)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
43.42   43.43   43.43   43.43   43.43   43.43
```

So there is a difference but `coordinates(nuclides.grd)` gives me the error below stating its a single point, however there is a difference according to the summary
    coordinates(nuclides.grd) <- ~ x+y
    gridded(nuclides.grd) <- TRUE
    Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
    cannot derive grid parameters from a single point!

Comment: This isn't [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) because we don't have any data to run it ourselves to verify. Follow the included link to see how to create a sample dataset for testing. Also, are you sure decimal places are being "lost"? R doesn't always print all the digits to the console yet they are still retained. It's unclear to me exactly what you think is wrong. Is there code you can run that shows one result when you expect a different one?

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for your response. Below is the summary from x.range and y.range. As you can see there is a difference between min and max. summary(x.range)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -80.65  -80.64  -80.64  -80.64  -80.64  -80.63 
> summary(y.range)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  43.42   43.43   43.43   43.43   43.43   43.43                                                However what I get is an error from coordinates(nuclides.grd) <- ~ x+y
> gridded(nuclides.grd) <- TRUE saying grid parameters cannot be derived from a single point

Comment: Please edit the question and add the data in the question, not in the comments (unreadable as such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on your summaries the range of `x` is 0.02 and the range of `y` is 0.01. However, in your `expand.grid` call you ask for sequences from the min to the max with a step size of 3.5. So your `seq` calls will return 1 value each, and your `expand.grid` will be a single point.

I'd recommend replacing `by = 3.5` with `length.out = 10` in your `seq` calls. Then you'll get multiple values in the sequences and multiple points in our grid.

As a debugging technique, check your inputs! You said that the error was with `coordinates(nuclides.grd)` saying it's a single point. This is easy to verify! Check if `nuclides.grd` is a single point (yes, it is), so then look at where it's defined.

Comment: thanks a bunch. The 3.5 is the cell size I prefer. Is there another way to specify this property?

Comment: With your data, that's like asking me to bin the heights of people in my office into miles. Turns out everyone I work with is less than 1 mile tall, they're all in the same bin. According to your ranges, all your points are within .01, so they're all in the same bin of size 3.5.

Comment: You either need data that's covers an approximately 350 times larger area to get it to a 2x2 grid of cell size 3.5, or you need to adjust your preference for the grid size. Maybe you can do 3.5 minutes instead of 3.5 degrees?